# Run additional breaker to detached garage

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, detached-structure

I have a detached garage about 40' from my house. There is already an electrical panel out there but I run my business out there and use a decent amount of electricity. There is only one 120 breaker in the house on the main panel for it and lately the breakers keep tripping. Is the best way to fix this to have someone run more power from the house? Any advice on how to go about this? Rough cost estimates? Any advice or information would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Is the existing line out to the garage buried? Is it in conduit? What size is the cable (the outer jacket usually has markings which denote the size, if the cable is exposed at all)? What size is the breaker in teh garage (I assume 15 or 20 A)? Questions about cost are off-topic here, since they vary so much, so I'd suggest editing your question to remove that aspect.

Comment: Does your main breaker panel have at least one unused slot (for an additional breaker)?  What is in the garage's breaker panel?

Comment: How many square feet are in the garage, and what other loads are you running in there?